# Update mysql with character '

Tags: mysql

In my value i have the character ' and i get a error.

How can i fix that?

```
    UPDATE products
SET description = CASE
    WHEN id <= 350 THEN 'Sample description with ' character'
    ELSE 'sample description 2'
END
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [escaping special character in mysql statements while using UPDATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295644/escaping-special-character-in-mysql-statements-while-using-update)

Comment: Use `''` instead of `'`.

Answer (score 1):

Usual method for escaping characters in SQL is \ so

```
    UPDATE products
SET description = CASE
    WHEN id <= 350 THEN 'Sample description with \' character'
    ELSE 'sample description 2'
```

And if you want to know how to put a \ in there, you just double it up, ie `\\`

Answer (score 0):

Double the quote:

```
UPDATE products
SET description = CASE
WHEN id <= 350 THEN 'Sample description with '' character'
ELSE 'sample description 2'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

**phpMyAdmin** doubles the quotes. You can do this way:

```
UPDATE `products`
SET `description` = CASE
    WHEN `id` <= 350 THEN 'Sample description with '' character'
    ELSE 'sample description 2'
END
```